# Binding a click event to a checkbox seems to trigger the click twice

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to style a form using and icon font, CSS and jQuery. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="u"></span>
</div>
```

The input itself will be hidden, so the idea is when the div.checkbox is clicked, it will trigger a click on the input and then change the data-icon attribute on the span to display the icon font in the checked state.

Here's where I'm running into trouble. When I run this jQuery:

```
$('.checkbox').on('click', function(){
    $(this).find(':checkbox').click();
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

It logs:

```
clicked
clicked
```

I thought that e.stopPropagation would help, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: try this way http://jsfiddle.net/yNB23/1/ click on the text, and the checkbox will be checked.

Comment: I think it logs twice because the triggered click bubbles up to the div at which time you get the second click

Comment: Why are you using `$(this).find(':checkbox').click();`? its bubbling up

Comment: Huangism: that's what I figured. Any idea on how to prevent that?

Comment: Satpal: Because the input will be hidden with absolute position and margin of -9999px. So I need to have it that when the user clicks the parent div, the hidden input will be clicked in response

Comment: @BrianO'Neill any comment on my comment?

Answer (score 1):

On clicking the div(.checkbox) checkbox click event triggering automatically, so no need to trigger the click event of checkbox explicitly.

Use this code:

```
$('.checkbox').on('click',function(e){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! There's no event bubbling as said in comments. It is actually a expected result. Read on for why.

### So what is happening?

When the `div` is clicked, its handler is executed.

When checkbox is clicked using `.click()`, a click event will be triggered again as `checkbox` is a child of `div`

So, you can use this:

You can use this:

```
$('.checkbox').on('click', function(){
    if(event.target.nodeName!=='INPUT'){
       $(this).find(':checkbox').click();
       console.log('clicked');
    }
});
```

The above will make sure that the function gets executed only when `div` is clicked.

Answer (score -2):

Use the checked property instead to stop the click event bubbling:

```
$('.checkbox').on('click', function(){
    var box = $(this).find(':checkbox');
    box.prop("checked", !box.prop("checked"));
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qc5Ng/)

Or you can test against the target to ensure only clicks on the div are registered:

```
$('.checkbox').on('click', function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is(":checkbox")) {
        $(this).find(':checkbox').click();
        console.log("clicked");
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zT3sH/)

Comment: @AmitJoki Not sure I understand? Change what selector? And revenge for what??

Comment: You could have done a simple input[type="checkbox"] rather than finding where it is

Comment: No. That would return all checkboxes on the page? `:checkbox` is the equivalent of `input[type=checkbox]` and I use `find` to ensure scope is only to the clicked element...